# TCP packet interception and redirection under windows

Tags: windows, redirect, tcp, windows-firewall

I have been trying to find some way of redirecting outbound TCP packets under windows, but so far have not been successful. Does anyone know of any software/code bit that would do something like that?
I am not even sure it is possible with the windows stack.

I am looking at doing something similar to what "-j REDIRECT" is to iptables.

EDIT: to be more precise, what needs to be done here, is to transparently(ie without the original application having to do anything) redirect outgoing tcp packet with a certain destination port to a specific ip.(alternatively redirecting them to a local port would be fine too since I can then just use something like rinetd or any port forwarder)

Comment: http://blog.forret.com/2004/06/port-redirection-in-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Netsh is a command-line scripting utility that allows you to, either locally or remotely, display or modify the network configuration of a computer that is currently running.
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localaddress listenport=localport connectaddress=destaddress connectport=destport

Answer (score 0):

see BarbaTunnel here and use its port redirecting

[BarbaTunnel project](http://barbatunnel.codeplex.com/)